# Creating pandas aggregate column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm practicing stats and pandas and I want to create a third column called 'Mean' which works out the means of each grouped location so that each separate row can then perform calculations with it. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['Alaska', 'Alaska', 'Amsterdam', 'Amsterdam',
                                'Arkansas', 'Arkansas'],
                   'Number': ['300', '500', '250', '600', '400', '150']}
```

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image: Dataframe]

The real_deviations column is to give an idea of what I'd be using it for.
I figured it out using a rather long-winded way of groupby and merges but am stuck on trying to find a more streamlined solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To generate the location-specific mean, you need to do a groupby transform:

`df['mean'] = df.groupby('Location')['Number'].transform('mean')`

Then, you can proceed to calculate the deviations as:

`df['real_deviations'] = df['Number'] - df['mean']`

PS: be sure to convert your numbers in "Number" from str to int beforehand. A simple `df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(int)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

The core capability you need is [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

- calc **mean** of group per row
- calc additional columns using this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['Alaska', 'Alaska', 'Amsterdam', 'Amsterdam',
                                'Arkansas', 'Arkansas'],
                   'Number': ['300', '500', '250', '600', '400', '150']})
df["Number"] = df["Number"].astype(int)

df.assign(means=df.groupby("Location", as_index=False).transform("mean"),
          real_deviation=lambda d: d["Number"] - d["means"])
```

|  | Location | Number | means | real_deviation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alaska | 300 | 400 | -100 |
| 1 | Alaska | 500 | 400 | 100 |
| 2 | Amsterdam | 250 | 425 | -175 |
| 3 | Amsterdam | 600 | 425 | 175 |
| 4 | Arkansas | 400 | 275 | 125 |
| 5 | Arkansas | 150 | 275 | -125 |